# Are there really no consumer-available WiFi adapters supporting WOL?

Tags: wireless-networking, desktop-computer, wake-on-lan

I can't for the life of me find any wireless adapters, of any kind, supporting wake-on-lan. Is this technology really a "laptop" only technology?

Comment: You might have more luck if you search for PCI or PCIe based wireless cards (real ones, not PCI to PMCIA to a wireless PCMCIA card)

Comment: I have looked at primarily PCI cards, and can't find any. I'm aware of the situation with USB not being powered when off

Comment: From a manufacturers point of view USB wireless dongles just make more sense, so that will be the gross of the made and sold wireless cards. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the core problem here is the USB part. Whatever adapter you plug into the USB port has to be powered to function.

So this wouldn't be a limitation of the WiFi adapter, but one of the mainboard. Your mainboard would have to support keeping the USB port powered and accepting some sort of wakeup signal. This process is unlikely to be standardized.

This question also came up on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789171/turn-on-pc-with-usb-device

Comment: I'm not talking about USB adapters, but actual WiFi cards. I'm aware of the USB power problem :)

Comment: @Dynde: From what I read, it's only available through some on-board Intel adaptors (as you've already found out yourself). I would assume it's not possible because of similar reasons to the ones that apply to USB. Maybe WiFi would require more power than what is available when the computer is "unpowered".